# why doesn't d3.behavior.zoom().center() work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two buttons that zoom in and out. I am trying to get the zoom functionality to center in the middle so when i zoom in it zooms in the middle and not to where the buttons are. I've defined a zoomlistener variable like so.

```
var width = 800;
var height = 500;

var zoomlistener = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .center([width / 2, height / 2])
  .on("zoom", redraw);
```

Then called it with the following...

```
var zoomfactor = 1;
d3.select(".zoomin").on("click", function (){
    zoomfactor = zoomfactor + 0.2;
    zoomlistener.scale(zoomfactor).event(d3.select(".graphmap"));
});

d3.select(".zoomout").on("click", function (){
    zoomfactor = zoomfactor - 0.2;
    zoomlistener.scale(zoomfactor).event(d3.select(".graphmap"));
});
```

But when i zoom in it still zooms where the buttons are.

.graphmap is

```
var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "graphmap");
```

and finnally redraw is

```
function redraw() {
  console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  g.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle ? I think its because your redraw function your using the d3.event.translate in your transform, so i think if you put 0,0 in there it should zoom from the center maybe ....

Answer (score 1):

Center is only supported for mousewheel movements. See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7ec977c95910dd026812) for an example.